# My application task can't be killed by cmd

Tags: c#, windows, taskkill

My C# and WPF application task can't be deleted by Task Manager or by console. It's a very big application but there's nothing new that can make the task 'bulletproof'

I tried:

```
wmic process where name="MyApp.exe" call terminate
```

But it says: return value 2 and it does't kill the process.

With

```
Taskkill /IM MyApp.exe /T /F
```

It returns "Access denied" even when I run it as administrator.

I don't really know what is happening and why Windows can't close the task of my application. If I restart the computer the task finish.

Comment: Your application may already be dead(-ish), and still hanging around because Windows is busy taking a memory dump after an unhandled exception, or it's otherwise still being referenced by other applications -- in other words, you've got a zombie. You can use something like Process Explorer (a little more sophisticated even than Task Manager) to verify if this is the case. The only way to get rid of a zombie process (other than a restart) is to identify where the open handles to it are coming from, and closing those (for example, by ending *those* applications).

Comment: Another, more pernicious cause of zombie processes is a process that gets stuck in I/O, because a process cannot exit until all pending I/O has been completed or cancelled. This usually only happens with bad device drivers, but if it does happen a restart is practically the only solution -- prevention is the only cure there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you, do you think it is possible to detect the taskkill from my application and thus close it from within?

Comment: If your process truly is a zombie, it should no longer be running code in the first place (just hanging around as a stub), and so it should not be able to do anything of that sort. Things like memory dumps will suspend the process, again rendering it unable to run any code. If in some way your process is still running, it could end itself with `Environment.FailFast`, but you could not do so with `taskkill` -- as far as it's concerned, the end is already there. Any signaling would have to be done with mechanisms your application itself exposes, and those need not work if it's being killed.

Comment: The surefire way to kill a process is to call `TerminateProcess()` on it, but I'm fairly sure that's exactly what `taskkill /f` ends up doing anyway. This should not, in theory, allow an application to keep running indefinitely -- the whole point of `TerminateProcess` is that you cannot dodge or circumvent it.

Comment: I've getting this with vstest.console.exe, and have been intermittently for a while. Doing the same exact thing. First, using `wmic` and then `taskkill` from an administrator command prompt. My anti-virus is also freaking out at the moment too. I feel like the two are related. The only thing that fixes this is turning the computer off. I can't even log out of windows to fix this.